# TypeError: <JIRA Status: name='Open', id='1'> is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, typeerror

I am writing an API for communication between Jira and another server.  I want to grab certain data from the Jira server and use it to populate some fields in the other software tool.

When i do this it works fine:

```
resp = s.get(url)
rec_data = resp.json()
data = json.dumps({"recordRevisionNumber": rev_id, "ELM_CSTM_TEXT1": "Open", "ELM_CSTM_TEXT2": "ARA-222"})
resp = s.put(url, data=data)
```

But I change out the hard coded "Open" and "ARA-222" with the variables "jira_id and "jira_status" I get an error.

```
data = json.dumps({"recordRevisionNumber": rev_id, "ELM_CSTM_TEXT1": jira_id, "ELM_CSTM_TEXT2": jira_status})
resp = s.put(url, data=data)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/byun/Desktop/Workspace/TopTeam_API.py", line 37, in <module>
data = json.dumps({"recordRevisionNumber": rev_id, "ELM_CSTM_TEXT1":     jira_id, "ELM_CSTM_TEXT2": jira_status})
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\json\__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <JIRA Status: name='Open', id='1'> is not JSON serializable
```

The variables are fine, they print out like this:

108 ARA-129 Open

108 ARA-128 Open

108 ARA-127 Open

108 ARA-126 Open

108 ARA-125 Open

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The jira_id was working fine.  The jira_status worked after I turned it into a string.

```
status = str(jira_status)
data = json.dumps({"recordRevisionNumber": rev_id, "ELM_CSTM_TEXT1": jira_id, "ELM_CSTM_TEXT2": status})
```